# Open directory that are too long in html

Tags: html, internet-explorer, directory

I want, when clicking the link, to open a directory.
I have this snippit:

```
<a href="\\Share\folder\folder\folder\folder\folder">Link</a>
```

when clicking, Internet Explorer Security pops up and I can click allow. This works, but if the directory is way to long, over 270 charactors, what I get is the page that says:

```
"Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage... etc."
```

Is it possible to achieve what I want and how?

**ADDED:**

This is what my html file contains created in notepad

```
<p>
    30-04-2012 13:10:23 <br>
    A little test to se what happens <br>
    Characters counted 270 <br>
    <a href ="C:\Users\pham000p\Desktop">test<a/>
</p>
```

Comment: why would u wanna make a 270 character folder o.O?

Comment: It's not me making the folder that long xD There are several folders that contains another folder and another folder etc. In the end, the directory name is longer then 260. There are many of them and finding them manually is a pain in somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is to add another share on the server which gives you direct access to one of the deeply nested folders.

Another solution is to use `mklink`:

```
mklink /d C:\folder \\Share\folder\folder\folder\folder\folder
```

will allow you to access the deeply nested folder as "C:\folder"

Note that `\` is an illegal character in HTML URLs; use `/` instead.

Comment: I'm not able to modify the share so that's not an option. Also i don't want to create a new folder. Everything has to be in a html file created in notepad. The content of the html file is added at the top.

Comment: You have two options: a) your solution (which doesn't work at all) or b) get a new share from your sysadmins. Yes, it's effort that you'd like to avoid but there is no other solution. So you either change the world or you give up. Your choice.